# Angular 7 environment variables string literal expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I have different paths for staging/production that I would like to keep in environment.ts and envornment.prod.ts per the documentation: [configuring-application-environment](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments). I have a relative path for the file I want to access and use it works fine if I just type it in: `import json_data from '../../folder/file.json'` When I try to use the same path from the environment file I get an error TS1141: String literal expected. I can console.log(environment.path) and I get the same path without quotes `../../folder/file.json;`

I've tried using .toString() and 
`` `${environment.path}` `` I've also tried escaping ' so that the value prints the same `'../../folder/file.json'`

I have also tried setting the value to string when declaring it `const url: String = environment.path` I'm using this inside a mock-data.ts file and using to generate the data I need for the app.

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  all_hosts_url: '\'../../nodeServer/s/output/hosts.json\'',
  connections_url: '../assets/data/connections.json',
  DOMAINS_URL: '../assets/data/domains.json'
};
```

mock-data.ts

```
import { environment} from '../environments/environment';


const _all_hosts_url: String = environment.all_hosts_url;
console.log(_all_hosts_url);


 import json_data from all_hosts_url;
```

Comment: Could you please add here some code example?

Comment: Sure. I've tried string  and String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't import a module defined in a variable. That's why it explains a string token.

Instead of loading modules in a dynamic fashion, load possible modules and use a condition to use the specific data you need for a given environment.

```
import { environment} from '../environments/environment';
import dev from 'path/to/dev/file';
import prod from 'path/to/prod/file';

const json_data = environment.production ? prod : dev;
```

Comment: so create an array of possible urls locally and check whether the env. is production or dev?

Comment: No, you can't import from arrays either. Import module by module into separate identifiers/variables

Comment: so set json_data_dev = import from 'dev/file/url'; Then if(env.value=dev){}

Comment: @1Bladesforhire yes, along these lines, I'll update the answer.

Comment: With angular beta 8 and "module": "esnext" you can use the dynamic `import()`